# aligning social media icons in HTML email header

Tags: html, css, email, alignment

I need your help. I am currently trying to create an HTML email. I would like to have my logo on the left side of the header and the social media icons at the bottom right. The only issue is that the social media icons are being displayed at the top instead of the bottom. How can I fix this? I have tried using vertical-align, but it doesn't work. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Tried vertical-align

```
                <td align="left" style="padding: 10px 0;">

                    <table border="0" width="2" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" class="container550">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="2" height="30" style="font-size: 30px; line-height: 30px;">
                                    &nbsp;
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <table border="0" width="200" align="right" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" class="container550">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="vertical-align: bottom">
                                    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/EmailonAcid" style="display: block; width: 50px; height: 50px; color: #3498DB; border: 0px !important;" rel="noopener">
                                        <img width="50" height="50" border="0" style="display: block; width: 50px; height: 50px;" alt="facebook" src="https://i.imgur.com/LT8fn9f.png">
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                </td>
                                <td style="vertical-align: bottom">
                                    <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/EmailonAcid" style="display: block; width: 50px; height: 50px; color: #3498DB; border: 0px !important;" rel="noopener">
                                        <img width="50" height="50" border="0" style="display: block; width: 50px; height: 50px;" alt="twitter" src="https://i.imgur.com/xG6UbfZ.png">
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                </td>
                                <td style="vertical-align: bottom">
                                    <a target="_blank" href="http://www.linkedin.com/company/email-on-acid?trk=cp_followed_name_email-on-acid" style="display: block; width: 50px; height: 50px; color: #3498DB; border: 0px !important;" rel="noopener">
                                        <img width="50" height="50" border="0" style="display: block; width: 50px; height: 50px;" alt="linkden" src="https://i.imgur.com/A5oi9zh.png">
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                    <table border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <a target="_blank" href="https://i.imgur.com/FkhEl63.png" style="display: block; width: 200px; height: 111px; color: #3498DB; border: 0px !important;" rel="noopener">
                                        <img width="200" height="111" border="0" style="display: block; width: 200px; height: 111px;" alt="facebook" src="https://i.imgur.com/FkhEl63.png">
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    
                </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap your tables in `<td>` you can leverage `vertical-align:bottom;` on one of those elements and move the icons down. Email CSS usually (unfortunately) requires a lot of table elements within more table elements

```html
<table style="width:100%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="left" style="padding: 10px 0;">
        <table style="width:100%;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <table border="0" width="2" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" class="container550">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td width="2" height="30" style="font-size: 30px; line-height: 30px;">
                        &nbsp;
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                <table border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <a target="_blank" href="https://i.imgur.com/FkhEl63.png" style="display: block; width: 200px; height: 111px; color: #3498DB; border: 0px !important;" rel="noopener">
                          <img width="200" height="111" border="0" style="display: block; width: 200px; height: 111px;" alt="facebook" src="https://i.imgur.com/FkhEl63.png">
                        </a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
              <td style="vertical-align:bottom;">
                <table border="0" width="200" align="right" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" class="container550">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="vertical-align: bottom">
                        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/EmailonAcid" style="display: block; width: 50px; height: 50px; color: #3498DB; border: 0px !important;" rel="noopener">
                          <img width="50" height="50" border="0" style="display: block; width: 50px; height: 50px;" alt="facebook" src="https://i.imgur.com/LT8fn9f.png">
                        </a>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                      </td>
                      <td style="vertical-align: bottom">
                        <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/EmailonAcid" style="display: block; width: 50px; height: 50px; color: #3498DB; border: 0px !important;" rel="noopener">
                          <img width="50" height="50" border="0" style="display: block; width: 50px; height: 50px;" alt="twitter" src="https://i.imgur.com/xG6UbfZ.png">
                        </a>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                      </td>
                      <td style="vertical-align: bottom">
                        <a target="_blank" href="http://www.linkedin.com/company/email-on-acid?trk=cp_followed_name_email-on-acid" style="display: block; width: 50px; height: 50px; color: #3498DB; border: 0px !important;" rel="noopener">
                          <img width="50" height="50" border="0" style="display: block; width: 50px; height: 50px;" alt="linkden" src="https://i.imgur.com/A5oi9zh.png">
                        </a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```